# How can I switch between two tableAdapters for SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I have two identical databases, one on a local server, the other in the cloud. both connection strings are stored in the app.config.
for both databases i have created a dataset and their adapters in visualstudio.
The client should be able to select at runtime by a parameter which tableAdapter he should use.
I want to process the data from both databases in the same class (identical structure and data)
therefore i need to switch between `Test.TestSetTableAdapter` and `Test.TestSet1TableAdpater`.
Furthermore the object `TestSet DataSet1`should also match the required type.

How can I change the reference to the namespace of these adapters at runtime?
Or is there a better way to handle this?

Ex:

```
namespace Test.TestSetTableAdapter
{
    partial class valueTableAdapter
    {
       ...
    }
}

namespace Test.TestSet1TableAdapter
{
    partial class valueTableAdapter
    {
       ...
    }
}

namespace Test
{
    class database
    {
        private static TestSet DataSet1;
        
        public Test() 
        {
            DataSet1 = new DataSet1();
        }
        public string[,] getValues()
        {
            TestSetTableAdapter.valueTableAdapter value = new TestSetTableAdapter.valueTableAdapter();
            value.FillBy(DataSet1.value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The adapter comes from a connection.  So an application can have more than one connection and each adapter is associated with a connection.

Comment: I think your question is not clear. Can you tell me what is the difference between the two tableadapter? or what is the depend on selecting table adapter about the parameter?

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
The tableadpaters retrieve the same data from two different databases. So they differ in the name and the connection string.
However, I have found a solution to change the type of the adapter at runtime. I define the variables as dynamic and decide which adapter to use at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need different datasets if the db schemas are identical; just create one DataSet in the designer. You can change the connectionstring a tableadapter uses by

- (maybe) clicking on the TableAdapter in the DataSet designer and setting the ConnectionModifier to public (if the default setting is no good for you because the TA code is in a different assembly to the code using it)
- changing the connection with `myTableAdapterX.Connection.ConnectionString = ...`

This way you can have either one or more DataSet instances and one or more tableadapter connected to different DB

If you are copying data from one db to another you can have one DataSet instance and one tableadapter and toggle the connectionstring or one DataSet instance and two TA instances with different connection strings.

If you are using two different db at the same time you would probably have two DataSet instances (to keep the data separate) and either one TA (and toggle its string all the time) or two TA (with different connection strings)